# Solaris: Equivalent command for chronyc sources and chronyc tracking

Tags: unix, solaris, chrony

As per title I want to check output of the equivalent command but on a Solaris 11 box.

Is there a similar command?

Answer (score 1):

In Solaris 11 you have standard `ntp` daemon so you can use command:

```
ntpq -p
```

to get the list of peers. And with this command you can see also some local time sync parameters:

```
root@sol1:/etc/inet# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+time.cloudflare 10.74.8.178      3 u   15   64    3    9.287  -241.90 210.255
*mail.eban-meban 147.125.80.35    3 u   36   64    1    4.415  -192.07  16.270
-purple.bonev.co 151.237.71.222   2 u   14   64    3    5.197  -242.41 219.576
+ntp.netguard.bg 20.39.126.15     2 u   47   64    3    4.570  -162.62 147.576
```